# walk / traverse a disjoint set that has union rank and path compression

Tags: data-structures, linked-lists, union-find, disjoint-sets

I'm studying CLRS section 21.3, which introduces a union rank + path-compressed implementation of disjoint set. The implementations of MAKE-SET, UNION, LINK, and FIND-SET on p 571 of the book all work with nodes themselves, where each node has a `parent` pointer and `rank`.

Exercise 4 in that section claims that if you wanted to traverse all the nodes in the set (e.g. to print them) you only need **a single extra attribute** for each node, and the book claims that you can implement this *without* sacrificing the asymptotic complexity of union rank + path compression.

The data structure that immediately comes to mind is a circular list with single (not double) links. In this case, the "single extra attribute" the exercise asks for would be the `next` pointer of each node. We could just maintain that list in parallel with the disjoint-forest + union rank + path-compression.

However, the problem is that when trying to merge two sets, you would also need to merge their circular lists, and for a singly linked circular list, I'm pretty sure you **cannot combine them into one without traversing through one of them first**. This traversing would certainly destroy the asymptotic efficiency of union rank + path compression here.

Of course, you could slightly augment the circular list by keeping track of both its head *and* the node *before* the head, i.e. the tail. However, in order to do this, you can no longer work directly with the nodes, but would need to maintain a `circ-list` object (one for each set) with `head` and `tail` pointers. This would also mean that you can no longer call UNION on two nodes directly, but rather need to maintain a `set` object that has a pointer to its `circ-list` object as well as its `root`. All this seems to be somewhat more than the "exactly one extra attribute for each node`, since you also need O(1) extra attributes for each set.

Is what the exercise asking for actually possible, or do I need to make one of the concessions above?

Answer (score 1):

None of the hacks in the question are necessary, since it's definitely possible to merge two singly linked circular lists without maintaining any additional tail pointers.

Suppose you have heads `x` and `y` of two separate circular lists. We first save `xn = x.next`. Then, set `x.next = y.next`. Then, set `y.next = xn`. After these, it's easy to see that the two circular lists have been merged.

Answer (score 0):

Let `X` and `Y` be the two sets to merge. Each element has a `next` pointer that ensures that if you follow the pointers, you visit all elements before you get back to the start.

Let `tailX := root(X).next`, and `tailY := root(Y).next`.

Set `root(X).next := tailY` and `root(Y).next := tailX`.

As you can see, starting from `root(X)` now takes you to the end of `Y`, through `Y` to the end of `X` and back to `root(X)`.